# Internationalization for richfaces custom skin

Tags: internationalization, richfaces, skin

We are using some custom skin for rich faces and below are 2 properties file for `packed` and `packedCompressed`

```
mySkin-packed-resource-mappings.properties
mySkin-packedcompressed-resource-mappings.properties
```

This property file has a mapping for home_icon e.g.

```
images\:home_icon.png = org.richfaces.staticResource/4.3.5.Final/Packedorg.richfaces.images/home_icon.png
```

My questions are:

1. How these does this mapping is used for richfaces custom skin? as I
   could not find any reference in my code for this key
   images:home_icon.png
2. Does richfaces support internationalization for custom skin
   resources like above one?
3. If answer to above question is yes and assuming that this mapping is
   for default English language, how can I add a mapping for another
   language like Arabic?

Please correct me if I have understood it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skin has nothing with internationalization. Skin properties setup colors, fonts, font sizes for different parts of UI. Internationalization files used for text setup and not related to skins.

About your questions:

1) regular RichFaces skin property file does not contain icon related properties, like `images\:home_icon.png`;

2) internationalization is not related to custom skin;

3) you can add internalization support for any language you want, but it is not related to skin properties.

On other side, it is totally valid to use `background-image: "#{a4jSkin.imageUrl('inputBackgroundImage.png')}";` in ecss files, but it has nothing with internationalization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is some context related info
1. These are our custom skin files so it contains such images

Moreover the images we are using in this property file are language specific e.g they contain English text which is bad practice from from UX point of view. So I guess we have 2 options

1. convert these images to be language neutral so they can be used across all languages
2. reference these skin images from JSF page instead of property file, which I don't know how to do. Can you put some light in that area?

Comment: You can separate text related images from skin simply using image servlet and (languge related) parameter. I have similar situation where skin and images are different for different tenant of the same application. But skin properties are siting in custom skin files, images (like logo and supporting images) are sitting in DB (accessible via image servlet).